# Proving function at a value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a non-constant function that preserves addition and multiplication
i.e. $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b) $ and $f(a * b) = f(a) * f(b) $

Prove $f(2) = 2$

I'd like any input if I approached this correctly:

$f(2) + f(2) = f(2 + 2) = 4$ by arithmetic? 
$f(2 + 2) = f(2) + f(2) = 4$
$f(2) = 2 $ so:

 $2 + f(2) = 4 $
,then subtract 2 from both sides to get:
$f(2) = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what a ring homomorphism is?
At any rate, maybe you can try to find out what $f(1) = f(1*1)$ is.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what ring homomorphism is.

Comment: I was just curious... you don't need to know what it is to do this problem.

Comment: $f(1) = f(1 * 1) = f(1) * f(1)$ , then $f(1) = f(1) * f(1)$, divide both sides by $f(1)$ to get $1 = f(1).$ Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: What if $f(1) = 0$?

Comment: Then your function is constant because $f(n) = f(n*1) = f(n)*f(1) = 0$, which is false by assumption. So the only option is that $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: $f(1)$ cant equal zero or else your function is constant. Since $f(1) \neq 0$, you can divide both sides of your equation by $f(1)$ just like you did. Therefore, your proof works and $f(1) = 1$. Then $f(2) = f(1+1)$.

Comment: If $f(2)=f(1+1)$ then $f(1 + 1 ) = f(1) + f(1)$
$f(1) = 1$ therefore: $1 + 1 = 2 = f(2)$ Yes?

Comment: Yup! Good to go

Comment: Thanks GDAL, you've been awesome help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you derive $f(2+2)=4$; furthermore, you nowhere use the fact that $f$ is non-constant (which you should use, as otherwise the constant function $f \equiv 0$ satisfies).

Note that $f(2)=2f(1)$, so it suffices to show that $f(1)=1$. Let $a$ be such that $f(a) \neq 0$, which exists as $f$ is not zero everywhere. Then we have $f(a \cdot 1) = f(a) \cdot f(1)$, yielding $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Why does the $f(a)$ disappear?

Comment: Divide by $f(a)$, which is nonzero.

Comment: I guess I'm asking why wouldn't it be $1/f(a)$ instead. 

Also, how do I incorporate the fact that $f$ is non-constant into the proof?

Comment: Am I able to start with $f(2) + f(2) = 4$?

Comment: Are you able to prove $f(2)$ directly instead of $2(f(1))?$