# Characterizing certain real functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functions

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707161/proving-function-at-a-value), I became curious about these functions, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with the property that $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$ and $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$.

Clearly the only constant function with this property is $f(x) \equiv 0$.

The non-constant ones are precisely the ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$, and you can easily show that they must satisfy $f(q) = q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to understand what happens to these $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ (the irrational numbers), clearly if $f$ is continuous then $f(p) = p$ for $p \in \mathbb{Q}^*$.

My question is, what values can $f$ take for $p \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ when $f$ is not continuous? I am thinking that for algebraic numbers the same thing happens (e.g $f(x) = x$), at least I am able to see that the possible values of $f$ for an algebraic number is finite, but I don't what else to say.

Thanks,

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Q}^\ast$ denote the field of algebraic numbers in $\mathbb{R}$? And are you interested in ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$, or of $\mathbb{Q}^\ast$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I thought $\mathbb{Q}^*$ was standard notation for the irrational numbers, I will clarify it, thanks. And I am interested in the endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ are a little boring. If $x \geqslant 0$, then

$$f(x) = f(\sqrt{x}^2) = f(\sqrt{x})^2 \geqslant 0,$$

so all ring endomorphisms map non-negative numbers to non-negative numbers. Hence they are monotonic, $x < y \Rightarrow f(y) = f(x + (y-x)) = f(x) + f(y-x) \geqslant f(x)$. Since a ring endomorphism leaves all rational numbers unchanged, and a monotonic function has at most jump discontinuities, it follows that the only ring endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity. It can't have a jump discontinuity, or it would leave some rational numbers out, hence it is continuous, and a continuous function that leaves $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed must be the identity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was suspecting exactly that :)